# Format negative decimal number with extension kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, string-formatting

I have a simple problem for which I didn`t find a solution. I am having large negative number ex(-6763.98) what I want is something like this ex($-6.78K). A found a lot of solutions that work for positive numbers but none that work for negative. This is the code that I am having right now.

```
const val COUNT_DIVISOR = 1000
       const val COUNT_DIVISOR_FLOAT = 1000.0
       fun getFormattedNumber(count: Long): String {
        if (count < COUNT_DIVISOR) return "" + count
        val exp = (ln(count.toDouble()) / ln(COUNT_DIVISOR_FLOAT)).toInt()
        return resources.getString(
            R.string.decimal_format_long_number_price,
            count / COUNT_DIVISOR_FLOAT.pow(exp.toDouble()), EXTENSION[exp - 1]
        )
    }
```

Comment: would this help ? "if (count < 1000.0 && count >-1000.0)"

Answer (score 2):

The [natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm) is not defined for negative values so the function `ln` will return `NaN` (not a number) for negative inputs.

From `ln` Kotlin [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/ln.html).

```
Special cases:
ln(NaN) is NaN
ln(x) is NaN when x < 0.0
ln(+Inf) is +Inf
ln(0.0) is -Inf
```

You have to make sure that the input is always a positive value in order to calculate the exponent correctly.

```
val exp = (ln(abs(count.toDouble())) / ln(COUNT_DIVISOR_FLOAT)).toInt()
```

Another problem is the first `if` check, which returns the input value itself for all inputs smaller than `COUNT_DIVISOR`. You have to allow large negative inputs through there as well.

```
if (count > -COUNT_DIVISOR && count < COUNT_DIVISOR) return "" + count
```

All together

```
const val COUNT_DIVISOR = 1000
const val COUNT_DIVISOR_FLOAT = 1000.0

fun getFormattedNumber(count: Long): String {
    if (count > -COUNT_DIVISOR && count < COUNT_DIVISOR) return "" + count
    val exp = (ln(abs(count.toDouble())) / ln(COUNT_DIVISOR_FLOAT)).toInt()
    return resources.getString(
        R.string.decimal_format_long_number_price,
        count / COUNT_DIVISOR_FLOAT.pow(exp.toDouble()), EXTENSION[exp - 1]
    )
}
```

If you want the result to always have 2 decimal places, consider any of these

```
val result = count / COUNT_DIVISOR_FLOAT.pow(exp.toDouble())

// This will use the root language/region neutral locale
// it will use the dot '.' as the decimal separator
"%.2f".format(Locale.ROOT, result)

// This will use the default locale
// it will use '.' or ',' as the decimal separator, based on the user settings on the target system
"%.2f".format(result)

val localeDefinedByYou = ... // or define a specific locale
"%.2f".format(localeDefinedByYou, result)
```